# CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints line breaks even when there is space available on the same line

Tags: macos, core-text, text-rendering

We are trying to get the suggested frame size using the Core Text API **CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints**.

Let, **E = \uFFFC ; W = \u200B ; S = \u00A0**

The **CTFrameSetter** is created with the following attributed string:

**WSESWWSESW**

The character S and E are given **CTRunDelegates** which have the **CTRunDelegateGetWidthCallback** that return **0** and say **100** respectively.

When the following code is executed :

```
auto frameOptions = @{ (id)kCTFrameProgressionAttributeName: @(kCTFrameProgressionTopToBottom)) };
auto constraintSize = CGSizeMake(200, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CFRange fitRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);

auto pathSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter_.get(), CFRangeMake(0, 0),(CFDictionaryRef)frameOptions, constraintSize, &fitRange);
```

**The pathSize returned by the API comes out to 100 and we get two separate lines**

We then create the CTFrameRef using the following piece of code:

```
auto rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, pathSize.height);
auto path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, nil));
auto frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter_.get(),
    CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, (CFDictionaryRef)frameOptions));
```

**Question**:

1. Why does the CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints return a pathSize which has a width of 100 when clearly the constraint width (200) should be sufficient to accommodate the entire text in a single line.
2. How does CoreText decide which glyps/character range from attributed string should be put together in a single run?
   In the above example we get the following two lines :

Line 1: W S E SWW          (4 CTTextRun)

Line 2: S E SW             (3 CTTextRun)

Can somebody please help me with answers to these two questions related to the abovementioned scenario. Thanks in advance!

### **Edit 1:**

Adding some more context to the problem and our current approach:
[Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLpNx.jpg)

Please refer to the image above for reference to "Parent", "Child1", "Child2".

"Parent" represents the box/rect that we want to layout and compute sizes for. We want to put the text in the "Parent" box. "Child1", "Child2" are represented by 'E' characters in our text.

1. First, we try to compute the size for the "Parent" box.
2. We use the computed size of the "Parent" box as constraints for the
   **CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints** and then use its return value to create **CTFrame**

**Size Computation** : The size computation of "Parent" box depends of multiple factors - there could be a specified size as a external parameter, or it could come from its container box, or could be equal to the size (clamped by some min, max) enough to fit its text content.
So, it is not always unconstrained (single line) or, sometimes even not dependent on the text content.

Let's look at the case when the computation is dependent on the text content:

So we calculate the width of the text without any constraints using:

```
CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter_.get(), CFRangeMake(0, 0),
            (CFDictionaryRef)frameOptions, CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX), &fitRange);
```

This returns the value of 100 (child1) + 100 (child2) = **200 pts exactly**. Let say we have enough space and 200 pts is what is set as the size of the "Parent" box.

**Text Layout** : At this point, we only have the computed size of the "Parent" Box and no information on how it was calculated.

If now we now use the constraints of **200 pts** with **CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints**, it returns 100pts and breaks the text in two lines.

This is where we have a problem - the unconstrained text size when used to create CTFrame gives an unexpected line break.

Comment: It would be helpful to show your actual setup code, and the results. In particular, how are you applying your attributes. What you describe doesn't match how the runs are breaking up. And your output includes "A" and "B" which you don't define. Also, CTFramesetter sometimes introduces a little breathing room (often 1 pt), so I wouldn't necessarily expect that two 100 pt characters would fit in precisely 200 pts. I would experiment with increasing your rect width until you see it fit on one line, and see how much extra you need. (But it could also be bugs in your attributed string.)

Comment: Updated the output. Thanks, @RobNapier for the suggestions. I tried increasing the width of the rect - increasing it by 1pt made the text fit in one line and solved the problem. Do you have ideas on in which scenarios is this "breathing room" needed by CTFrameSetter? And also, on what factors does the magnitude of this extra space needed can depend?  Isolating such scenarios will help us to enlarge the constraints accordingly.

Comment: While I have generally found it to add an extra point, it is not documented, and not promised to be stable across releases or configurations. It can depend on the font, the specific glyphs, the screen resolution, or the total size. (With Apple's new "UI fonts," there seemed to be some subtle tweaks in layout.) If you want to know how large CTFramesetter is going to make things, you need to make one, and ask it. Just make your horizontal space unbounded (see `greatestFiniteMagnitude`, or just use 10,000). If you can enlarge the constraints, they weren't the real constraints.

Comment: Also, if you want things to fit one line, you probably don't want a framesetter at all. You can use CTLine directly. You probably want CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions or CTLineGetTypographicBounds, depending on your layout needs. Some glyphs draw outside their em boxes, and some glyphs line up better when they are slightly shifted within the line fragment, so you can't make a lot of assumptions. You just need to let the system do the layout, and ask it for the results.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, as discussed in the comments, because CTFramesetter has various rules that may add padding or make glyph adjustments. It depends on lots of things (and is not promised to be consistent over time), so you can't guess. Just ask CTFramesetter (or CTLine) what the size is, and adjust your layout accordingly. Or if you have a hard constraint (this must fit in 100 points), then set that and it'll wrap. But if you say "well, 101 points would have been ok, too," then 100 points wasn't the constraint. Make your constraints the actual constraint, or leave it unconstrained (in which case yo probably want CTLine, not CTFramesetter).

To the second question, a CTRun is a range that has all the same attribute values attached. NSAttributedString is smart about this, and can merge together equivalent neighboring regions even if you set the attributes in overlapping ways. It does not *promise* that this is always done, however. It is legal for consecutive CTRun objects to have the same attributes. This can happen when the attributes are applied in complicated ways, or when attributed strings are joined together.

If you check the attributes for your NSAttributedString, you'll find that there is likely some difference between the first and second characters, the second and third characters, and then characters 4-6 have exactly the same attributes.

Comment: Edited the post to add some more context to the first problem. I understand your point on enlarging the constraints - we know the constraints precisely - and were using the same. We were just exploring if this 'extra space' is small enough (and predictable) to have a lesser visual impact and can be added to the constraints to get the right breaking behaviour (just as a hack for now)

Comment: The space is not predictable. For a given set of inputs, including OS version and hardware, it's always going to be the same; it doesn't change randomly. But changing any factor can change the result. Now in practice it is very rare for there to be OS changes at this level, so you can roll the dice and take your chances. But if you want the correct answer, then you get that by doing the layout and asking. There's no documentation of the algorithms, and they're not promised.

Comment: To your specific case, you'll either need to just add an extra point (which generally seems to be enough, but is not promised), and try the layout, or you'll need to iterate back and forth between the child and the parent until you get a stable layout. I've done that several times in projects. It's not trivial, but it can be done. Or you can get rid of CTFramesetter and do more of the layout by hand so you know exactly where things are going and possibly adjusting them (CTRun will still help you a lot here). I very rarely use CTFramesetter. I mostly exclusively use CTLine and CTRun.

Comment: Or move up the stack, and use TextKit rather than Core Text. NSLayoutManager is quite powerful, especially on Mac. (On iOS, I find that it if you use it in unexpected ways, it can often crash, and the documentation doesn't explain the "expected ways" well.) Or do your layout with Autolayout, which already handles a lot of these "parent and child need to coordinate their sizes and find a stable solution."